# Using Collaborative Forecasting and need to migrate data to custom Forecasting Object

Tags: forecasts-collaborative

I am transitioning 'Scheduled Revenue' from Collaborative Forecasting to a custom Forecasting Object. I cannot find a list of the objects in Collaborative Forecasting and how they are used. Where can I find it?

Comment: why was this downvoted? Help the brother out... easy question, easy answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mark, consider this schema diagram (includes object names) per the SFDC documentation. This should get you on your way.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_forecasts3.htm